# MS ACCESS Managing deletions with one-to-one relationship

Tags: ms-access, relationship

I have a working Sales Order form, and I need to add a subform for Returned Goods. I have a one-to-one relationship set up between the ID of my `SalesOrderDetails` and my `SalesOrderReturns`, because each line item should never have more than one `SalesOrderReturn` line item.

I want to be able to delete `SalesOrderReturns` from the subform datasheet, while not deleting the `SalesOrderDetail` it's tied to. Let's say it was entered on accident. On the other hand I want to prevent deletion of the `SalesOrderDetail` if it's tied to a `SalesOrderReturn`.

The way I have it set up now, I cannot delete `SalesOrderDetails` if they have a linked `SalesOrderReturn`. But when I delete the `SalesOrderReturn`, it deletes the line item in `SalesOrderDetails`. I just want to remove the Return without removing the line item.

Comment: Sounds like JOIN type on relationship link is backwards. If you don't change that, don't activate Cascade Delete on the link.

Comment: Cascade delete and update are both disabled.

Comment: That's odd. And what is the JOIN description?

Comment: Now in doing a little more thought; I suppose I may want multiple `SalesOrderReturns` so I can keep track of the return dates. Now I have a one-to-many relationship and it seems to be working much better now. I was having all sorts of issues before, including my form adding new rows to `SalesOrderDetails` when I added a new `SalesOrderReturn`